# Finding vertices in a mesh that are within certain proximity of each other

Tags: algorithm, search, 3d, spatial, mesh

I have a 3D mesh that is comprised of a certain amount of vertices.

I know that there are some vertices that are really close to one another. I want to find groups of these, so that I can normalize them.

I could make a KD and do basic NNS, but that doesn't scale so well if I don't have a reference point.

I want to find these groups in relation to all points.

In my searches I also found k-means but I cannot seem to wrap my head around it's scientific descriptions to find out if that's really what I need.

I'm not well versed in spatial algorithms in general. I know where one can apply them, for instance, for this case, but I lack the actual know-how, to even have the correct keywords.

So, yeah, what algorithms are meant for such task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple idea that might work:

1. Compue a slightly big bounding volume for each vertex in the mesh. For instance is you use a Sphere, use a small radius for it e.g., the radius can be equal to the length of the smallest edge of the mesh.
2. Compute the intersection of bounding volumes for each vertex. Use a collision detection algorithm for that such as the I-Collide. Use a disjoint-set datastrcture for grouping the points in collision.
3. Merge all the points residing in the same set.

You can fine-tune the algorithm by changing the size of the bounding volumes. Also you can use this algorithm as a starting point for a k-means algoritm or other sound clustering technique.